# need to use concat with list of find method in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x

i am using cakephp 3.1. in that i need to use concat the firstname and lastname with space using list of find method..

I tried below code it return with semi columns but i need space instead of semi columns.

**Code**:

```
 $query = $articles->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id',
        'valueField' => ['firstname','lastname']
    ]);
    $data = $query->toArray();
```

**I got below result :**

```
 $data = [
        1 => 'rahul;patel',
        2 => 'raj;patel',
    ];
```

But i need space instead of semi column (;).

Please guys help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it look like if you `var_dump` the `$query`?

Comment: i already sent output

Comment: You put the output of `$query->toArray();` but not just `$query`

Comment: actually $query return object..but output is same only object and array diff

Comment: Not sure if this will help you but you can check, http://pritomkumar.blogspot.sg/2013/09/concat-two-different-fields-in-cakephp.html

Comment: thanks but it also not working..

Comment: yuppp right...thanks :)

Comment: @KamleshGupta I've just added a third option to my answer that I've overlooked initially (someone else mentioned it in another answer)

Answer (score 0):

Currently in the documentation for 3.0 I don't see the support to add parameters in the find function, but I'm not very familiar with cakephp http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

I would try something along these lines. I've commented out an alternative possible return in the array_map. I hope this helps.

```
  $query = $articles
    ->find()
    ->select(['id','firstname', 'lastname'])
    ->order(['created' => 'DESC']);

  $data = array_reduce($query, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item->id] = $item->firstname.' '.$item->lastname;
    return $carry;
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i don't need using like this i know about this...i want in list

Comment: @KamleshGupta does this help? https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/3597

Comment: no actually i want key as id and value as first name and lastname with space between fname and lname

Comment: @KamleshGupta I've updated the code to give you your desired result. I understand this doesn't use the exact process you'd like to use within CakePHP.

Comment: thanks for your time dude

Comment: You're welcome @KamleshGupta